# twitter bootstrap table css

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap

i am developing an asp.net c# application using the twitter bootstrap framework.

i am trying not to add change or add any CSS so wanted to know the following

i have a asp.net gridview, which eventually renders as table. i wanted to know what is the css class to be applied for tables?

ASP.NET
C#
Twitter Bootstrap

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="VideoList" style="border-  collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>Senior Care</td><td>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>Cardiac Catheterization Lab</td><td>
                        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

any ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the minimum styling can be added just with the "table" class.  That is:

```
MyGrid.CssClass = "table";
```

Optionally, you can include additional table formatting such as

```
MyGrid.CssClass = "table table-striped table-bordered";
```

To see some more noticeable styling